# Delete all spaces in a worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I am writing a function to remove all spaces (and later new lines) in a spreadsheet for use in a comparison tool.

I have code that runs without errors, but it doesn't seem to do anything.

I am trying to loop through all the characters in a string, and if it is a space, turn it into nothing.

```vb
Sub removeSpaces(ws1 As Worksheet)
    Dim r As Long, c As Integer, s As Integer, cellContent As String
    Dim myChar As Variant
    
    Dim lr1 As Long, lr2 As Long, lc1 As Integer, lc2 As Integer
    Dim maxR As Long, maxC As Integer, cf1 As String, cf2 As String
    Dim rptWB As Workbook, DiffCount As Long, SameCount As Long, TotalCount As Long
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.StatusBar = "Deleting Spaces..."
    With ws1.UsedRange
        lr1 = .Rows.Count
        lc1 = .Columns.Count
    End With
    maxR = lr1
    maxC = lc1
    For c = 1 To maxC
        For r = 1 To maxR
            cellContent = ws1.Cells(c, r)
            For s = 1 To Len(cellContent)
                myChar = Mid(cellContent, s, 1)
                If myChar = " " Then
                    myChar = ""
                End If
            Next
        Next
    Next
    Application.StatusBar = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Sub callRemoveSpaces()
    removeSpaces ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
End Sub
```

Answer (score 4):

There's no need to loop. Use [`Range.Replace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.replace):

```
ws1.UsedRange.Replace What:=" ", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart
```